# Wordpress outer shortcode parsing html tag of inner shortcode's content

Tags: wordpress

I'm going to write some example code, so it's a shortened example of the issue I'm experiencing.

Let's say I have the following text stored in the database:

```html
[form]
  <ul>
    [each name="upgrades"]
      <li><input type="checkbox" [value name="upgrade_name" id="1"] />[value name="upgrade_name" id="2"]</li>
    [/each]
  </ul>
[/form]
```

If I run `do_shortcode` on this text, the shortcodes INSIDE html tags INSIDE the `each` content is parsed instead of being deferred to the `each` shortcode. However, shortcodes that are not in html tags in the `each` content are not parsed until the `each` shortcode runs `do_shortcode` on it's content, which should be the correct behavior.

In otherwords, the `value` shortcode with id `1` is parsed too soon (on the `form` shortcode pass), but the `value` shortcode with id `2` is not parsed until the `each` shortcode runs `do_shortcode` on it, so it produces the correct value.

I know I can set the ignore_html flag on the form shortcode to `true`, but that is incorrect as a user may want to have html tags parsed for shortcodes.

Is there a workaround for this behavior?

Wordpress version 4.6.1

EDIT: Adding reproducible code

Create a new plugin with this code:

```html
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Broken Shortcodes
Description: Shortcodes should not jump the gun in parsing html tag shortcodes of inner shortcode content.
*/

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');

add_shortcode('form', function($atts, $content){
  echo "<textarea>This is the form's content:\n".$content.'</textarea>';
  return "<textarea>This is the rendered form shortcode:\n".do_shortcode($content).'</textarea>';
});

$bad_global_variable = 'first';

add_shortcode('value', function($atts, $content){
  global $bad_global_variable;
  return $bad_global_variable;
});

add_shortcode('each', function($atts, $content){
  global $bad_global_variable;
  $_content = '';
  foreach(array('second', 'third', 'fourth') as $v){
    $bad_global_variable = $v;
    $_content .= do_shortcode($content);
  }
  return $_content;
});



?>
```

Create a page with this text:

```html
[form]
  [each]
    <div [value]>[value]</div>
  [/each]
[/form]
```

The output is incorrect:

```html
  
<div first>second</div>

<div first>third</div>

<div first>second</div>

<div first>fourth</div>

<div first>second</div>

<div first>third</div>

<div first>second</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick workaround is to parse your own shortcodes out of html tags.

So you text would look like:

```html
[form]
  [each]
    <!-- Notice curly brackets -->
    <div {value}>[value]</div>
  [/each]
[/form]
```

Then your each shortcode might look like this:

```html
add_shortcode('each', function($atts, $content){
  global $bad_global_variable;
  $content = preg_replace('/\{([^}]+)\}/', '[$1]', $content, -1);
  $_content = '';
  add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', 'parse_tags', 10, 2 );
  foreach(array('second', 'third', 'fourth') as $v){
    $bad_global_variable = $v;
    $_content .= do_shortcode($content);
  }
  remove_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', 'parse_tags', 10, 2 );
  return $_content;
});

// This might be necessary depending on your use-case
function parse_tags($tags, $context){
  $tags['input']['value'] = true;
  return $tags;
}
```

But, this should not be a solution to something seemingly so simple. I think the Shortcode API needs some TLC.

See ticket here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33134